# How to convert Array of Strings with space into single Array list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array as below

```
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];
```

Now i want to convert this array like below.

```
var result = ["john", "doe", "first", "robert", "way", "jason", 
"doe", "alex"];
```

Quick explanation is i need convert each array element of string into array and reset it into the array. Array index is not important. 
I tried arr.split(" ") even arr.toString() and then arr.split(" "). I don't know what i'm missing here.

Comment: And can you share the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) :

```js
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];

console.log(arr.join(' ').split(' '));
```

> *If your Strings have more than one space separating your words :*

Add `.filter(Boolean)` to remove the empty Strings

```js
var arr = ["john doe    first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];

console.log(arr.join(' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: This doesnt work if the array contains (for some reason) 2 spaces together.

Comment: @CristianS. I added a fix.

Comment: Thanks Cristian S. for pointing out.

Comment: @parth I already fixed it.

Comment: Back to you i guess

Comment: This still doesnt work if the string contains 3 spaces together. What Im trying to say is that is a very bad practice to find strings like that `'   ' . Use regex!

Comment: @CristianS. Yes it does. Just read the whole answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use `reduce`, `concat` and `split`

```
arr.reduce( (a , c) => a.concat(c.split(/\s+/)), [])
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"].reduce( (a , c) => a.concat(c.split(/\s+/)), []);
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `concat` method with spread syntax `...` to add to a new array and `map` and `split` methods to split each element on white space.

```js
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];
var result = [].concat(...arr.map(e => e.split(' ')));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spread` operator in a `forEach` loop:

```js
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];
var res = [];
arr.forEach((item)=>{ 
   var tempArray = item.split(' ');
   res.push(...tempArray);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];
var finalArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  arr[i].split(' ').forEach(function(item) {finalArray.push(item);});
}

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];

function formatArray(array){
  var newArr=[];
  array.forEach(function(item){
    item.split(' ').forEach(function(itemSplitted){
      newArr.push(itemSplitted);
    });
  });
  return newArr;
}

console.log(formatArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["john dvoe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"]; 
var arr2= arr.map(function(item){return item.split(" ")});
var result=[].concat.apply([],arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["john doe first", "robert way", "jason doe", "alex"];
let result = []
arr.map((e) => {
  result = result.concat(e.split(/[ ,]+/))
})

console.log(result);
```